# Mocha, chai, webdriverio testing: How can I click out of a modal pop up dialog and continue on with the regular web flow

Tags: mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

For a web page I am trying to write a test for, a modal appears sometimes. I'll like to write the test case such that if that does happen, I'll click the x to exit out of it and continue on with the test, else just do the test.

So far I have this:

```
client
    .init()
    .url('https://www.mywebsite.com/')
    .isExisting('#simple-modal.auth-modal.open.visible').then(function(value){
       // Select the X button: would like to client.click('#xbutton') 
      //when modal finishes loading
    })
    .click('#mybutton')
    .getText('.browse-header').then(function(value) {
        console.log('Title is : ' + value);
    })
    .end();
```

It seems that if I try to split the client object into 2 sections such that I init() and declare the url, then add a semicolon, then figure if the modal exist, add semicolon, then complete the rest of the test, the client doesn't complete the test. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to run this test with the wdio test runner? I think it is much easier as all commands are running synchronous. It would be able to do it in standalone mode like you have too, here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/christian-bromann/9e64aa3ca568e29b9a7b76d99d608900

Comment: Thanks Chris, if I were to have multiple test would I be able to declare the client in the beforeeach method and then use the client object later on?

Comment: basically yes but I'ld recommend the wdio test runner. It takes care of that stuff for you, you just need to define multiple capabilities and it starts the sessions for you. You only need to write the tests then.